# how do I assign variable variables te right way in Python?

Tags: tkinter

I

```
var1 = BooleanVar()
var2 = BooleanVar()
etc

    
Checkbutton(master, variable=var1).grid(row=1, column=1)
Checkbutton(master, variable=var2).grid(row=2, column=1)
etc
```

and what is the best way to read them?

Comment: Are you looking for: `var1.get()`

Comment: yes but can you make the variable variable?  like varx,get()

Comment: It's not clear why  you need our help. The way to set them is documented. Have you don't any research before asking?

Comment: i have tried it by myself for a few hours, the thing is that there are 100 checkboxes. so im looking for a way to assign them using a for loop. I tried using arrays and lists and the .format command. But nothin seemed to work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def print_all():
    result = [var.get() for var in vars]
    print(result)

root = tk.Tk()

print_all_button = tk.Button(root, text="Click me", command=print_all)
print_all_button.pack()

vars = []

for i in range(5):
    var = tk.BooleanVar(root)

    button = tk.Checkbutton(root, variable=var)
    button.pack()

    vars.append(var)

root.mainloop()
```

It creates 5 check buttons in a for loop and stores all of the `BooleanVar`s in a list called `vars`. Later in the function I can call `var.get()` for each variable.

Comment: Thanks! this is excactly what i needed. .append and root are new for me. But i will be able to figure those out. Thanks a lot

Comment: @GijsVanleeuwen `.append` is a method that you can call on lists to add something to them. `root` is what I called my window. Happy to have helped